# How to Check SharePoint 2010 State Machine workflow error logs?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Please guide me how to check state machine workflow error as well as please let me know how we get/track state machine workflow logs?. 
We have SharePoint 2010 environment. 
Thanks and Appreciate for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

State machine workflows didn't exist in 2010. Perhaps you are using 2013, or perhaps there's a different feature you're thinking of? While there are more advanced options, the one simple options is adding logging messages in the workflow itself, which is helpful for tracking down all sorts of issues including logic errors. If the workflow has stopped with an error message, the error should be on the workflow status page, and more information could be in the SharePoint ULS logs.

Comment: Thanks for reply mike, Basically this is a visual studio based custom workflow in SP2010. this is multilevel of WF,  after complete 3 levels getting an error.

Comment: Same answer, add logging to the workflow, or check the ULS logs. Or, if this is in dev, set a breakpoint in Visual Studio and attach to the process to debug: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms455354(v%3Doffice.14)